# Type annotate a function parameter as derived from multiple abstract base classes in Python

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to type annotate a function in Python 2 according to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). The function accepts a container which should implement both `__len__` and `__iter__`. The original code where I want to add this annotation is quite complex, so consider an example function  which returns the product of all `int`s in a container `s` if `len(s)` is even and returns 1 otherwise.

If I wanted to annotate a container where only `__len__` is needed, I would have annotated it as `type: (Sized) -> int`. If I wanted to annotate a container where only `__iter__` is needed, I would have annotated it as `type: (Iterable[int]) -> int`. But how do I perfectly annotate a container where I need both?

I tried this as per [Piotr-Ćwiek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945742)'s suggestion:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from typing import Sized, Iterable

class SizedIterable(Sized, Iterable[int]):
    pass

def product2(numbers):
    # type: (SizedIterable) -> int
    if len(numbers)%2 == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        p = 1
        for n in numbers:
            p*= n
        return p

print(product2([1, 2, 3, 4]))
print(product2({1, 2, 3, 4}))
```

but this failed with this error:

```
prod2.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "product2" has incompatible type List[int]; expected "SizedIterable"
prod2.py:18: error: Argument 1 to "product2" has incompatible type Set[int]; expected "SizedIterable"
```

Comment: Hm. There's `typing.Union`, but no `typing.Intersection`, and no type that specifically matches something with both `__len__` and `__iter__`.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't work. I also checked other possibilities, with no success (e.g. mimicking class definitions from `typing` module or using `__instancecheck__`). These solutions worked dynamically (`isinstance()`) but were not recognized by mypy. There may be no support yet for it, but it may be coming in the future. See: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Comment: For now I'm using `Union[Sequence[int], AbstractSet[int]]`. That's not exactly what I want, but it's bearable.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.6, there's `typing.Collection` that works almost perfectly for your use case (it also derives from `Container`, but realistically anything that you want to use will likely have `__contains__`). Unfortunately, there's no solution for python 2.

The reason `SizedIterable` doesn't work is that by deriving it from `Sized` and `Iterable`, you are only telling mypy that it's a subtype of those two types; mypy does *not* conclude that any type that's a subtype of `Sized` and `Iterable` is also a subtype of `SizedIterable`.

Mypy's is perfectly logical; after all, you wouldn't want this code to type check:

```
class A(Sized, Iterable[int]):
  def g(self) -> None:
    ...

def f(x: A) -> None:
  a.g()

# passes type check because [1, 2] is Sized and Iterable
# but fails in run-time
f([1, 2])
```

It would be too tricky if mypy treated your class definition differently just because its class body is empty.

In order for mypy to understand your intent, mypy would need to add a new feature to its type system.

Two options for such a feature are being considered at the moment:

- [intersections](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) (as pointed out by  @PiotrĆwiek); what you're asking for is an intersection of `Iterable` and `Sized`
- [structural typing](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/11); this is much simpler than general intersections, but sufficient for your use case, since all you need is for the `numbers` argument to have `__len__` and `__iter__` methods

Mimicking `typing` class definitions or using `__instancecheck__` won't work because (as someone explained to me just recently) under no condition will `mypy` ever run the code you wrote (i.e., it will never import your module, never call your function, etc.). This is because mypy is a static analysis tool that doesn't assume that the environment to run your code is even available during its execution (e.g., python version, libraries, etc.).